# FFMPEG - Store FFPROBE's duration output as a variable

Tags: video, command-line, cmd, ffmpeg

I wanted to use a video's duration in the "enable='between(t,0,0)" field to make sure that I overlay an image at 1/3 of the video's duration every time.

According to FFMPEG's info on their site, I need to use this

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.mp4
```

it does return a value but I can't seem to be able to set it to a usable variable, I already tried by using

```
set duration=ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.mp4
```

And then referencing it via %duration%, but no luck.

Is there a way to do this, am I doing something wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try [`FOR /F` Loop command: against the results of another command.](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command designed for processing output of a console application is [FOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for).

A batch file code like below can be used to capture output of [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) and assign it to an environment variable.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if not exist input.mp4 goto :EOF
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('ffprobe.exe -v error -show_entries format^=duration -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1:nokey^=1 input.mp4 2^>^&1') do set "duration=%%I"
echo Duration is: %duration%
endlocal
```

The command **FOR** with option `/F` interprets the string enclosed in `'`  as command to execute of which output written to **STDOUT** should be processed line by line. **FOR** respectively `cmd.exe` processing the batch file starts for this purpose one more command process in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line between `'` appended as additional arguments and captures everything written to handle **STDOUT** of the additionally started background command process.

Windows command processor `cmd.exe` processing the batch file interprets among space also comma `,`, semicolon `;`, equal sign `=` and OEM encoded no-break space   (with decimal code value 255) as argument separator. For that reason it is necessary to escape each `=` with `^` in the command line to pass to `cmd.exe` started in background to get the equal signs interpreted as literal characters by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file instead of argument separators.

`2>&1` redirects output written to **STDERR** (standard error) to handle **STDOUT** (standard output) which is processed by **FOR**. It is necessary here to escape the operators `>` and `&` with `^` to apply this redirection on execution of *ffprobe* and not interpreting the redirection already on parsing **FOR** command line. See the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)). This redirection of **STDERR** to **STDOUT** is perhaps not necessary if *ffprobe* outputs on correct usage the requested information to **STDOUT**. But it could be important if *ffprobe* outputs the data to **STDERR**.

So executed in background is following with Windows installed into `C:\Windows`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c ffprobe.exe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.mp4 2>&1
```

That is an absolutely valid execution of Windows command processor according to syntax as explained by the help output on running `cmd /?` in a Windows [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window.

The option `delims=` in double quotes after `/F` disables splitting up the captured line into multiple tokens (strings) using space and horizontal tab as string separators as it defines an empty list of string delimiters. `"delims="` is most likely not necessary for output of *ffprobe* with the used command line. But I don't have *ffprobe* installed and it was not posted in question what it outputs.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution to be the best for me, for extracting bits of information into variables from ffprobe.

Maybe it can help others in the future:
[Bash Script to get info from ffprobe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554931/bash-script-to-get-info-from-ffprobe)

**Example:**

```
INPUT='C:\Users\tl\Downloads\f18\MyWork\test.mov'
eval $(ffprobe -v quiet -show_format -of flat=s=_ -show_entries stream=height,width,nb_frames,duration,codec_name $INPUT);
width=${streams_stream_0_width};
height=${streams_stream_0_height};
bitrate=$((${format_bit_rate}/1000));
echo $width,$height,$bitrate;
read
```