# batch store ffprobe as variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ffprobe

I'm looking to store the video codec as a variable in a batch file to automate some video conversion, but not wanting to convert things which are already the right codec.

This produces a the codec successfully (hevc)

```
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries` stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 video.mkv
pause
```

However I've been unable to store that result in a variable, I've followed a number of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40097486/ffmpeg-store-ffprobes-duration-output-as-a-variable) which suggest this layout.

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 video.mkv') do set "codec=%%I"
echo %codec%
```

however this results this error: "Argument 'noprint_wrappers' provided as input filename, but 'codec_name' was already specified."

I'm really not sure where to go as all my reading suggest that this is the correct way to store the variable.

Comment: within the `'` (single quotes), escape each `=` with a caret (`^`) thus : `...ult^=noprint_wrappers^=1:nokey^=1 vi...` to inform `for` that the `=` are literal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [solution to the example question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40102931) already shows you what you have missed and explicitly instructs you to escape the equal-to signs like `^=`, so why do you not do it?

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream^=codec_name -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1:nokey^=1 video.mkv') do set "codec=%%I"
echo(%codec%
```

The problem is that the `=`, besides <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, `,`, `;` and the non-break space, ASCII `0xFF`, constitutes a token separator to the command interpreter, so it gets lost (or replaced by a <kbd>SPACE</kbd>) when the command line is parsed. Escaping annulates the special meaning and preserves the character literally.

As an alternative to escaping, [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) can be used, like this:

```cmd
set "CommandLine=C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 video.mkv"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('!CommandLine!') do set "codec=%%I"
echo(%codec%
endlocal
```

This works, because the command line string appears quoted in the assignment statement (`set`), so any token separators and other special characters are not recognised, and the variable `CommandLine` is expanded *after* the command line has been parsed, so special characters like token separators are not recognised at that moment any more.

Regard that the value of `codec` is no longer available beyond `endlocal`, unless you establish [suitable countermeasures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3262287).

Comment: Are you sure about the output line in the delayed expansion variant `echo(%codec%`? Should it not be `echo(!codec!)`?

Comment: @PeterCo, having delayed expansion enabled does not disallow to use normal (immediate) `%`-expansion; but yes, `!codec!` would generally be better since `%codec%` could lead to problems when the expanded string contains exclamation marks `!` on its own, which would then be consumed by delayed expansion…